# Creating UDF compatible with DataFrame and SQL API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write and UDF that would work in Dataframes in Spark SQL.

Here is the code

```
def Timeformat (timecol1: Int) = {
    if (timecol1 >= 1440)  
        ("%02d:%02d".format((timecol1-1440)/60, (timecol1-1440)%60))  
    else 
        ("%02d:%02d".format((timecol1)/60, (timecol1)%60))
}

sqlContext.udf.register("Timeformat", Timeformat _)
```

This method works perfectly for the sqlcontext

```
val dataa = sqlContext.sql("""select Timeformat(abc.time_band) from abc""")
```

Using DF - Gets an error
`val fcstdataa = abc.select(Timeformat(abc("time_band_start")))`

This method throws an type mismatch error.

```
<console>:41: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Int
```

When i have re-written the UDF as below, works perfect for the DF but doesnot work in the Sqlcontext. Is there any way to solve this issue without creating multiple UDF's to do the same thing

```
val Timeformat = udf((timecol1: Int) => 
    if (timecol1 >= 1440)  
        ("%02d:%02d".format((timecol1-1440)/60, (timecol1-1440)%60))  
    else 
        ("%02d:%02d".format((timecol1)/60, (timecol1)%60))
)
```

I am pretty new to scala and spark, What is the difference between two declarations. Is one method better than other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to use UDF here but if you really want this simply don't use anonymous function. Take the function you already have (the one `Int => String`) and wrap it using UDF:

```
def Timeformat(timecol1: Int): String = ??? 
sqlContext.udf.register("Timeformat", Timeformat _)
val timeformat_ = udf(Timeformat _)
```

Alternatively you can `callUDF`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.callUDF

abc.select(callUDF("Timeformat", $"time_band_start"))
```

That being said non-UDF solution should be preferred most of the time:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, format_string}

def timeformatExpr(col: Column) = {
  val offset = when(col >= 1440, 1440).otherwise(0)
  val x = ((col - offset) / 60).cast("int")
  val y = (col - offset) % 60
  format_string("%02d:%02d", x, y)
}
```

which is equivalent to following SQL:

```
val expr = """CASE
  WHEN time_band >= 1440 THEN
      FORMAT_STRING(
          '%02d:%02d', 
          CAST((time_band - 1440) / 60 AS INT),
          (time_band - 1440) % 60
      )
  ELSE 
      FORMAT_STRING(
          '%02d:%02d', 
          CAST(time_band / 60 AS INT),
          time_band % 60
      )
END"""
```

which can be used in raw SQL as well as `DataFrame` with `selectExpr` or `expr` function.

**Examples**:

```
val df = Seq((1L, 123123), (2L, 42132), (3L, 99)).toDF("id", "time_band")

df.select($"*", timeformatExpr($"time_band").alias("tf")).show
// +---+---------+-------+
// | id|time_band|     tf|
// +---+---------+-------+
// |  1|   123123|2028:03|
// |  2|    42132| 678:12|
// |  3|       99|  01:39|
// +---+---------+-------+

df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT *, $expr AS tf FROM df").show
// +---+---------+-------+
// | id|time_band|     tf|
// +---+---------+-------+
// |  1|   123123|2028:03|
// |  2|    42132| 678:12|
// |  3|       99|  01:39|
// +---+---------+-------+

df.selectExpr("*", s"$expr AS tf").show
// +---+---------+-------+
// | id|time_band|     tf|
// +---+---------+-------+
// |  1|   123123|2028:03|
// |  2|    42132| 678:12|
// |  3|       99|  01:39|
// +---+---------+-------+
```